# Fingering first measure Funeral March

Tags: piano, fingering, beginner

Is the 5 5 fingering for the left hand, first measure, correct?
I ask it because it is for me as a beginner difficult to reposition my left pink quickly on the right place. Is there a good alternative?

[image: First measure of Funeral March, rev. Ricardo Boppre, Piano Collection for Beginners, Grade 2]

Answer (score 4):

There's rarely any 'correct' fingering! There's *suggested* fingering (bit like guitar tab!) but it's been done usually by someone who it works for. And if that's not you, you don't *have* to use it!

It does seem a bit jumpy, playing with pinky then playing another, higher note with pinky again. Certainly the F notes need pinky, then a sort of hand roll through index, up to A with thumb, and back to C again with index, making the stretch down to F not-too-bad using pinky again. As always, try out as many different fingerings as you can with any piece - I'm still doing that after 60+ yrs playing! But I reckon most will bottom out at 5-2-1-2.

Answer (score 3):

The 5-5 is a viable option, particularly since the pedal is there to help cover the gap.

My preferred fingering would be 5-2-1, because the 5-2 is fairly comfortable, and I have a wide span between 2 and 1.

Some people prefer 5-3-1.